# result set of SPARQL query against WIKIDATA ignores offset

Tags: select, sparql, wikidata

I expect to retrieve 10 citizens of Canada, whereas the result set ought to start at the lowest wikidata ID Q... it matches (i.e. the search should "start" at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1) :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel 
    WHERE { 
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 . 
    ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q16 . 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 
    } 
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

But the curent [result](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP27%20wd%3AQ16%20.%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%20%7D%20LIMIT%2010%20OFFSET%200) seems to provide arbitrary findings, e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q116544 (= ice hockey player Danny Gare)

I have not manually checked any entries for canadian citizens with lower WIKIDATA Q id's than Q116544, but I assume that there are some / many.

What do I have to add to get the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want this because ordering is expensive, but here we go:

#### First try

Simply using `ORDER BY` on the `?item`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE { 
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 . 
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q16 . 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 
} 
ORDER BY ASC(?item)
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The drawback, sorting is done lexicographically...

#### Workaround

Extract the number from the entity URI with [`strafter`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strafter) function:

1. extract value after http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q with

   `strafter(str(?item), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q")`
2. convert to integer value by using XPath constructor function [`xsd:integer()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#FunctionMapping)
3. `BIND` to variable

Final Query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE { 
   ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 . 
   ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q16 . 
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 
   BIND(xsd:integer(strafter(str(?item), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q")) as ?number)
} 
ORDER BY ASC(?number)
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Thanks! First try provided as first result wd:Q206, but then, after a huge gap, wd:Q1000439. I would assume that there are results in between, too. The workaround seems to be fine, though it is a costly query (~ 20s).

Comment: As I said, the first query sorts based on strings rather than integer values, i.e. `1 
10 
11 
.. 
19 
2 
20 
21 ` And of course, sorting is expensive.